# No bluetooth found in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bluetooth, dell, services

After the latest update I did (19/11/2020), I put my computer to sleep for a couple of hours, and when I tried to re-connect my bluetooth headset, I realized that bluetooth was suddenly OFF, and I could not turn it on by clicking the toggle button on settings.

I tried to restart my computer, run once again an `update` & `upgrade` on my system, but nothing worked.

Looking around at several different posts, I found out that by running `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status` I got that bluetooth.service was dead:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Νοε 21 01:22:46 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Νοε 21 01:23:26 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Νοε 21 01:28:48 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Νοε 21 01:29:45 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

I tried to start the service by running: `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` but the service did not start.

Poking around once again, I found that if I run `sudo modprobe btusb` and then `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` the service was able to start:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-11-21 01:31:18 EET; 1s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 5948 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 14199)
     Memory: 2.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─5948 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Νοε 21 01:31:18 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Νοε 21 01:31:18 mike-Inspiron bluetoothd[5948]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Νοε 21 01:31:18 mike-Inspiron systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Νοε 21 01:31:18 mike-Inspiron bluetoothd[5948]: Starting SDP server
Νοε 21 01:31:18 mike-Inspiron bluetoothd[5948]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

I then went ahead to check my bluetooth connectivity on settings, and for once again, I could not enable it.

In case it is of interest, here is a `uname -a` from my system:
`Linux mike-Inspiron 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And also I would to point out (since I saw it in other similar posts), that the commands `ls /sys/bus/sdio/drivers` and `mesg |egrep -i "blue|fw|firm|hci"` do NOT give me any output.

EDIT #1:

The command `dmesg |egrep -i "blue|fw|firm|hci"`  gives me the following output:

```
[    0.095463] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.145091] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.387256] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.387257] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.387263] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.387267] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.387270] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.387274] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.387278] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.387382] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.387385] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.388448] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000001109810
[    0.388581] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.388709] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.388709] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-54-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.389573] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.389575] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.389577] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.389599] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.389600] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-54-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.599864] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    0.613823] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    0.613826] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
[    0.654250] scsi host0: ahci
[    0.654528] scsi host1: ahci
[    0.654705] scsi host2: ahci
[    0.654833] scsi host3: ahci
[    0.722013] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.002015] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.285859] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.566001] usb 1-7: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.846001] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   16.918281] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[  586.264799] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  586.264867] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  586.264874] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  586.264878] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  586.264886] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  592.864305] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  592.864308] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  592.864317] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Try using dmesg not mesg and post the output.

Comment: @ubfan1 I added the output as an edit on the original post.

Comment: Looks good, but then I'd expect somr RFCOM and HIDP Bluetooth messages (maybe when a mouse connects?).  My lsmod output for bluetooth looks like:  
bluetooth             548864  32 btrtl,hidp,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm 
Do you have all those modules?

Comment: @ubfan1 The only line in `lsmod` that looks like the one you mention, is the following: bluetooth  548864  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb.